# Get Github Issue based only on title

Tags: performance, post, github, get, github-api

I need to modify the body of an existing GitHub issue in a Project. All I'll be passed is the title of the issue, and a word (the word exists in the body, and I'll just need to fill the checkbox next it).
It looks like to do this I'll need to use the [GET](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#get-a-single-issue) API to get the body of the issue, modify it, and then use the [EDIT](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#edit-an-issue) API to swap in the new body. However the GET API can only be called with the issue number. I need to do all this as quickly as possible. Is there some way to search via an API call?

Thoughts much appreciated!

Edit: All my issues are in the same project (and issue titles will be unique there). I've also recently discovered Github's GraphQL API, which may be applicable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [issue search endpoint with the `in` and `repo`¹ keywords](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues):

```
GET /search/issues?q=text+to+search+in:title+repo:some/repo
```

Of course, issue titles aren't guaranteed to be unique. You'll have to request each of the issues that comes back and see if its body contains the word you're looking for. Even in that case you could get multiple positive results.

It would be much better if you could search by issue number.

---

¹I've assumed that you really mean "repository" when you say "project". But if you're actually talking about [GitHub Project Boards](https://help.github.com/articles/about-project-boards/) you can use the `project` keyword as well or instead.

Comment: Good point Chris. All of the issues I'll be filtering on are in the same project. Perhaps I can just search within the project

Comment: @Acoustic77, I've updated my answer to show how to limit your search to a specific repository. You might have a convention that issue titles are unique within the repository, but nothing guarantees that. I think you'd be wise to assume that you may get back multiple results.

Comment: thank you! I did mean project, (but also the project they're inside is within one repository) so your search string helps either way!